# Store a directory as a File object or a String?

Tags: java

In my application I have a class called `MyObject`. This class must have a member that represents a directory (the object is going to write in this directory).

Should I use a `String` or a `File` object for this member?

Answer (score 5):

Use a `File` object. It's always best to choose an object type that most closely mirrors the usage of the data.

*Incidentally, you should never call your object `MyObject`. Pick a more meaningful name that describes the purpose of your object.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it matters much. Probably most clean would be to have a final File field, assuming you need to create a File object anyway.

Edit inspired by comment: What matters more is, if you have a getter for this member, should this getter return `File` or `String` or perhaps even `URL` or `URI`? That affects public API of the class, and that should be given some serious thought. And it may be easiest to just not provide getter until you need one (unless it is a library which you need to make "complete"), but instead just have a meaningful `toString()` override for debugging purposes etc.

Comment: @Thilo Why is that to be applauded? In terms of OO design, I think the correct choice is clear. Now, it happens that one can easily map between a `String` and a `File`, but is that any reason to think it shouldn't matter what you choose?

Comment: I wouldn't applaud it, but I do believe that you shouldn't let OO design dictate what you are comfortable with and you find readable. If you want to treat paths as String objects (which they are to be honest), just do it.

Comment: @DuncanJones Well, what is most appropriate is very situation dependent. What if it is user-entered string which is checked only later, is it appropriate to store as File then, or should become file only after it's been verified it actually is valid file name? As long as it is a private field, it really does not matter much, almost everything else in the program will matter more.

Comment: @hyde That's a good counterexample, fair enough. I'll stop hollering from beneath my bridge.

Answer (score 0):

files are terrible to test. try [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) - it will improve your design. i'm not aware of any file abstractions libraries but maybe you should consider looking for one. or at least try to split you business code from file handling code as much as possible